# Tab Error python

Tags: python

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
startTime = time.time()
numberOfSockets = 0
concurrent = 25
urls = []
urlsUsed = []

def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "http://www.twitch.tv/gbowtheking", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]   #replace twitch.tv/??? with your channel
        return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
        global numberOfSockets
        global numberOfViewers
        while True:
                if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
                        numberOfSockets += 1
                        print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
                        urls.append(getURL())

def view(): # Opens connections to send views
        global numberOfSockets
        while True:
                url=q.get()
                requests.head(url)
                if (url in urlsUsed):
                        urls.remove(url)
                        urlsUsed.remove(url)
                        numberOfSockets -= 1
                else:
                        urlsUsed.append(url)
                q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        for i in range(0, builderThreads):
                threading.Thread(target = build).start()

        while True:
                while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are built
                        time.sleep(1)

                q=Queue(concurrent*2)
                for i in range(concurrent):
                        try:
                                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                                t.daemon=True
                                t.start()
                        except:
                                print 'thread error'
                try:
                        for url in urls:
                                print url
                                q.put(url.strip())
                                q.join()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        sys.exit(1)
```

I get a taberror on this line

```
return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url']
```

full error is "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"
It seems my spacing is accurate but apparently not. 
Any ideas on how to fix it?  Could I be using an incorrect version of python?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a mixture of tabs & spaces to indent your lines...  don't do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tab is required at the `return` statement. (line 19) 
**Change This**

```
def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "http://www.twitch.tv/gbowtheking", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]   #replace twitch.tv/??? with your channel
        return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter
```

**To**

```
def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "http://www.twitch.tv/gbowtheking", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]   #replace twitch.tv/??? with your channel
  return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter
```

You can also check your future python code for indentation on http://pythoniter.appspot.com